# Purpose of VertexWeight

Tags: graphs-and-networks, documentation

I am trying to partition a graph into partitions of equal weight (on the vertex).

I looked at the documentation, and found [VertexWeight](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexWeight.html), which seems to attach a weight to a vertex.

In the details, it says:

> The weight  can be interpreted as cost or capacity, or have other special meanings for different graph computation functions.

But I cannot seem to find any mention of VertexWeight anywhere else. Its not in `FindGraphPartition` or `FindVertexCut`.

Is this property taken into account in those cases (specifically looking for `FindPartition`. If not, where is it used?

Comment: FindMaximumFlow